# What is the difference between a lognormal distribution and a normal distribution with a high degree of right skew?

Tags: terminology, normal-distribution

Pretty much the question. Is there a line (figurative) that separates when you'd use one term and when you'd use the other? Is there a distinctive characteristic of one that is not found in the other? Please help me understand. Thanks!

Comment: normal distribution has no skewness

Comment: A log-normal distribution has a pdf with a very specific curve, not just any distribution with that general shape.  Just like a parabola is a specific curve such as $y = x^2$, not just any curve with a U-shape.  If you have data and you want to test for log-normality, you can take the log and then check for normality using a standard technique like a QQ-plot or a [normality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test).

Comment: @JairTaylor Yes, in pristine theoretical conditions, but data can be messy. I assume there could be a distribution that appears highly skewed to the right, but whose natural log doesn't quite resemble a beautiful bell curve either (but comes reasonably close). In such a case, is there a threshold used to label it one way or the other, or a way to refer to it?

Comment: There's no specific dividing line.